# How to upgrade AWS EC2 from t2.2xlarge to t3.2xlarge?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an **t2.2xlarge** AWS EC2 instance that i need to change it's type to **t3.2xlarge**.
But when i try to start it i get an

> "Error starting instances The requested configuration is currently not
> supported. Please check the documentation for supported
> configurations."

When i run the check script everything is fine

https://github.com/awslabs/aws-support-tools/tree/master/EC2/NitroInstanceChecks

```
OK NVMe Module is installed and available on your instance
OK ENA Module with version is installed and available on your instance
OK fstab file looks fine and does not contain any device names.
```

And i also did all the checks described here

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/boot-error-linux-nitro-instance/

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids my-instance-id --query "Reservations[].Instances[].EnaSupport"
[
    true
]
```

Is there anything else i should change to be able to start it as **t3.2xlarge**?

To reproduce:

1. Create an t2.2xlarge instance with default settings
2. Stop it and change type to t3.2xlarge
3. Try to start it

More detailed info about instance

```
aws ec2 describe-instances
    {
        "Reservations": [
            {
                "Groups": [],
                "Instances": [
                    {
                        "AmiLaunchIndex": 0,
                        "ImageId": "ami-***********",
                        "InstanceId": "i-***********",
                        "InstanceType": "t2.2xlarge",
                        "KeyName": "***********",
                        "LaunchTime": "2020-11-24T06:11:41+00:00",
                        "Monitoring": {
                            "State": "disabled"
                        },
                        "Placement": {
                            "AvailabilityZone": "us-east-1e",
                            "GroupName": "",
                            "Tenancy": "default"
                        },
                        "PrivateDnsName": "ip-***********.ec2.internal",
                        "PrivateIpAddress": "***********",
                        "ProductCodes": [],
                        "PublicDnsName": "ec2-***********.compute-1.amazonaws.com",
                        "PublicIpAddress": "***********",
                        "State": {
                            "Code": 16,
                            "Name": "running"
                        },
                        "StateTransitionReason": "",
                        "SubnetId": "subnet-***********",
                        "VpcId": "vpc-***********",
                        "Architecture": "x86_64",
                        "BlockDeviceMappings": [
                            {
                                "DeviceName": "/dev/sda1",
                                "Ebs": {
                                    "AttachTime": "2020-10-06T05:07:35+00:00",
                                    "DeleteOnTermination": true,
                                    "Status": "attached",
                                    "VolumeId": "vol-***********"
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "ClientToken": "",
                        "EbsOptimized": false,
                        "EnaSupport": true,
                        "Hypervisor": "xen",
                        "NetworkInterfaces": [
                            {
                                "Association": {
                                    "IpOwnerId": "amazon",
                                    "PublicDnsName": "***********.compute-1.amazonaws.com",
                                    "PublicIp": "***********"
                                },
                                "Attachment": {
                                    "AttachTime": "2020-10-06T05:07:34+00:00",
                                    "AttachmentId": "eni-attach-***********",
                                    "DeleteOnTermination": true,
                                    "DeviceIndex": 0,
                                    "Status": "attached",
                                    "NetworkCardIndex": 0
                                },
                                "Description": "",
                                "Groups": [
                                    {
                                        "GroupName": "launch-wizard-1",
                                        "GroupId": "sg-***********"
                                    }
                                ],
                                "Ipv6Addresses": [],
                                "MacAddress": "***********",
                                "NetworkInterfaceId": "eni-***********",
                                "OwnerId": "***********",
                                "PrivateDnsName": "ip-***********.ec2.internal",
                                "PrivateIpAddress": "***********",
                                "PrivateIpAddresses": [
                                    {
                                        "Association": {
                                            "IpOwnerId": "amazon",
                                            "PublicDnsName": "ec2-***********.compute-1.amazonaws.com",
                                            "PublicIp": "***********"
                                        },
                                        "Primary": true,
                                        "PrivateDnsName": "ip-***********.ec2.internal",
                                        "PrivateIpAddress": "***********"
                                    }
                                ],
                                "SourceDestCheck": true,
                                "Status": "in-use",
                                "SubnetId": "subnet-***********",
                                "VpcId": "vpc-***********",
                                "InterfaceType": "interface"
                            }
                        ],
                        "RootDeviceName": "/dev/sda1",
                        "RootDeviceType": "ebs",
                        "SecurityGroups": [
                            {
                                "GroupName": "launch-wizard-1",
                                "GroupId": "sg-***********"
                            }
                        ],
                        "SourceDestCheck": true,
                        "Tags": [
                            {
                                "Key": "Name",
                                "Value": ""
                            }
                        ],
                        "VirtualizationType": "hvm",
                        "CpuOptions": {
                            "CoreCount": 8,
                            "ThreadsPerCore": 1
                        },
                        "CapacityReservationSpecification": {
                            "CapacityReservationPreference": "open"
                        },
                        "HibernationOptions": {
                            "Configured": false
                        },
                        "MetadataOptions": {
                            "State": "applied",
                            "HttpTokens": "optional",
                            "HttpPutResponseHopLimit": 1,
                            "HttpEndpoint": "enabled"
                        },
                        "EnclaveOptions": {
                            "Enabled": false
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "OwnerId": "***********",
                "ReservationId": "r-***********"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to launch a `t3.2xlarge` in `us-east-1e` and got the following error:

> Your requested instance type (t3.2xlarge) is not supported in your requested Availability Zone (us-east-1e). Please retry your request by not specifying an Availability Zone or choosing us-east-1a, us-east-1b, us-east-1c, us-east-1d, us-east-1f.

AWS probably doesn't have `t3.2xlarge` instances available in this AZ.

Comment: You're right, if i check the "Request Spot instances" option the only available AZ are: us-east-1a, us-east-1b, us-east-1c, us-east-1d, us-east-1f. I'll try to move my instance to one of the available AZ then. Thanks.

Comment: It worked. Here are the steps: 1) Stop instance 2) Right click on it / Image / Create Image 3) Go to Images / AMI, right click the AMI that was just created and launch it with the desired instance type (in my case t3.2xlarge). So it will be automatically assigned with the correct AZ. Thanks!